# Changed my display manager to lightdm-gtk-greeter. Now I can't login

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, lightdm, login-screen

Last night I edited the **default-display-manager** file and changed my default display manager from lightdm to lightdm-gtk-greeter. Then I edited the lightdm-gtk-greeter config file and changed the wallpaper. Now, when I reboot the computer I get a whole string of messages where the computer is booting up but it freezes and won't boot into the system. It just hangs there. How do I get back into my system? I'm running Xubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Comment: If you able to go to recovery console by grub and bypass xinit you could change to gdm or whatever you like. otherwise try CTRL+C and repeat it as often as you could before lightdm displays in a short sequence while booting may be it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is what did the trick for me. I received this advice from someone else. When the system hung up I pressed Ctrl-Alt-F1 and got to a virtual terminal. Then, I issued the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. That reset my display manager back to lightdm and I was able to sign in as normal. Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try, if you are using internet connection using Wired LAN then these may work for you:

Installing **GDM** (a display manager like lightdm) can fix your problem:

**Method 1:**

- This method works when you are able to go to at least the `command line interface`.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> when your system starts and starts freezing or black screen appears. It will let you to use Command Line Interface. Then login using your username and password, and try following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdm
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm

then selected gdm from the list, and restarted your system:
$ sudo reboot
```

Your system will be restarted with a login screen which will let you to access your system.

**Method 2**: If *1st* didn't work for you then you can try this method. But it would be very long for you:

**Here are the steps how to install using *2nd* method**

- Go to following link and download gdm for Ubuntu 12.04.2 amd64. (chose `ubuntu 
  proposed universe` out of three listed there.)

  http://pkgs.org/download/gdm
- Put the *.deb file just installed to any pendrive.
- Then login in save mode or `Recovery Mode`. After a lot of text displayed in black

  screen one window will come which list some options. First go to option **Grub**, it
  will mount your file system in read/write mode. Then chose **root** option in order
  to login as root. Then go to the pendrive where you saved the deb file. The drive 
  should be listed in in /media. I am assuming that you saved the file in `gdm` 
  directory inside `pendrive` (`pendrive` is the name of your pendrive)

  ```
  # cd /media && ls
  ```

  (which will list your `pendrive` if you don't get `pendrive`
   folder then go to **Mount Pendrive Section** at last, then come back here and continue to next step.)

  ```
  # cd /media/pendrive/gdm
  ```

  (go to gdm directory where .deb file is saved.)

  ```
  # dpkg -i *.deb
  ```

  (installing gdm)
  While installing gdm one window will come which will ask your to chose lightdm or gdm
  from the list. Chose gdm. If this window doesn't appear then try following command:

  ```
  # dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```

  (chose gdm) Then finally execute following command:

  ```
  # reboot (reboot your system)
  ```

**Mount Pendrive Section**

- Mounting pendrive while working in recovery mode.

Run this command:

```
    # fdisk -l
```

Find your device in the list, it is probably something like `/dev/sdb1`. Then execute other commands one by another:

```
    # mkdir /media/pendrive
```

- Run this command if your pendrive is formatted in FAT/FAT32.

  ```
  # mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/pendrive -o uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137
  ```
- Or this command if your pendrive is formatted in NTFS

  ```
  # mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/pendrive
  ```

Hope it will work for you.. For any further assistance please reply..